# Variables js scope in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp 3.x, i want to declare js vars in a custom script, in a view, and call this var in external js loaded in same view

This is code my view:

```
<?php //in my view:
   echo $this->Html->script('edit'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var my_var = 'try';
</script>
```

I want to call *my_var* also in edit.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable before the js include.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var my_var = 'try';
</script> 

<?php echo $this->Html->script('edit'); ?>
```